# How do closures capture values from previous calls?

Tags: swift, closures, nested-function

```
typealias IntMaker = (Void)->Int

func makeCounter() ->IntMaker{
    var n = 0 // Line A

    func adder()->Integer{
        n = n + 1
        return n 
    }
    return adder
}

let counter1 = makeCounter()

counter1() // returns 1
counter1() // returns 2
counter1() // returns 3
```

Isn't 'Line A' called each time we call `counter1()` ? meaning that `var n = 0` should be called every time...

Why is that the counter returns different values? Shouldn't they always be returning '1' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've called `makeCounter()` once. That creates your new closure, and assigns it to `counter1`. This closure closes over the mutable `var n`, and will remain captured as long as this closure exists.

Calling `counter1()` will execute it, but it retains the same captured `n`, and mutates it. This particular "adder" will ALWAYS capture this same `n`, so long as it exists..

To get the behavior you're suggesting, you need to make new closures which capture new instances of `n`:

```
let counter1 = makeCounter()

counter1() // returns 1
counter1() // returns 2
counter1() // returns 3

var counter2 = makeCounter()
counter2() // returns 1
counter2 = makeCounter()
counter2() // returns 1
counter2 = makeCounter()
counter2() // returns 1
```

Now both `counter1` and `counter2` each have their own separate instances of `n`.

Comment: How would you then reset a value each time you make a call? Perhaps knowing that would help me better understand

Comment: You would need to make a new closure with `makeCounter()` again. During the call to `makeCounter()`, a new `n` variable will be made, and a new closure will capture that new `n`. Then

Comment: The whole point of closures is the reference semantics. If you wanted value semantics, you could have just passed in n as a param to the closure. This would make a copy of `n` local to the closure, and independent of the outside one.

Comment: Or, if you want `makeCounter` to initialize `n`, put a statement to do so in the function.

Comment: It's much more clearer now. I get what happens, yet I don't understand **how Line A is called but not executed**  or is that it's not even called?

Comment: Line A is part of `makeCounter`; it is *not* part of `adder`/`counter1`.

Comment: @Honey Line A isn't called other than during the execution `makeCounter()` Line A makes a new `var n`, and it's done, It's over. Until you call `makeCounter()` again, Line A is irrelevant. The closure just captures the `n` that happens to exist after Line A

Comment: @ScottHunter Aha! So this means for every new function call... you will have a new `var n` but for *every execution* of `counter1` there would be no other **new** `var n`—that only happens during its instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, Line A *isn't* being called each time `counter1` is called.

The sequence of events is:

- `makeCounter` is called, which declares and initializes `n` (Line A), defines `adder`, and returns `adder` *in a context that includes `n` already having been defined and initialized to 1*.
- It is this function that was just returned that is assigned to `counter1`.  Because the Line A is not part of that function (`adder`/`counter1`), it does not get executed when that function is called.
- Each call to `counter1` is executed in that same context, which is why `n` retains its value across calls: they are all accessing the same `n`.

Comment: **1)** Your 2nd bullet, the word 'this' refers to what? Can you please make an edit. **2)** My question is why doesn't the context begin from `var n = 0` why is it only from the function call? You are saying what I **do** know. I don't know **why** it happens that way!

Comment: "this" is the function `adder`. The context is not the code that ran but the variables the code created and initialised. `var n = 0` is not part of the context, a variable `n` initialised to 0 is.