# Capture list in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an example:

```
class Animal {
    var stamina = 0

    func increaseStamina() {
        stamina += 1
    }
}

var a = Animal()

var closure = { [weak a] in
    a?.stamina = 10
}

a.stamina // 0
a.increaseStamina()
a.stamina // 1
closure()
a.stamina // 10
```

if I change the `closure` like this:

```
var closure = { [weak a] in
    a = Animal()
    a?.stamina = 10
}
```

then it prints something like this:

```
a.stamina // 0
a.increaseStamina()
a.stamina // 1
closure()
a.stamina // 1
```

Why is the last line different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do closures capture values from previous calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839020/how-do-closures-capture-values-from-previous-calls)

Comment: @Honey: I am not sure if that qualifies as a duplicate. It is related, but there are no capture lists in that question, and no classes (reference types).

Comment: @MartinR Ohhhhk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All entries in the capture list create a *local variable* in the
closure. It is initialized with the value of the variable
with the same name in the outer context, but can be modified
independently.

In your case

```
var closure = { [weak a] in
    a = Animal()
    a?.stamina = 10
}
```

`a` inside the closure is initialized with a weak reference to the `Animal` object created before, but it is independent of the outer `a` variable. `a = Animal()` creates a new instance and assigns the
reference to that local variable `a`. Because it is a weak reference,
the object is deallocated immediately (you can verify that
by adding `print(a)` in the closure). The outer variable `a`
still references the original object:

```
print(a.stamina) // 0
a.increaseStamina()
print(a.stamina) // 1
print(ObjectIdentifier(a)) // ObjectIdentifier(0x0000000100a03060)
closure()
print(ObjectIdentifier(a)) // ObjectIdentifier(0x0000000100a03060)
print(a.stamina) // 1
```

If you omit the capture list then `a` inside the closure 
and outside the closure refer to the same variable,
and a new instance can be assigned inside the closure:

```
var a = Animal()

var closure = {
    a = Animal()
    a.stamina = 10
}

print(a.stamina) // 0
a.increaseStamina()
print(a.stamina) // 1
print(ObjectIdentifier(a)) // ObjectIdentifier(0x0000000100b06ac0)
closure()
print(ObjectIdentifier(a)) // ObjectIdentifier(0x0000000100e00070)
print(a.stamina) // 10
```

For more information and details, see ["Capture Lists"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID544) in the Swift references (thanks so @Arthur for providing
the link).

Comment: Since I was curious too, [here is the relevant portion in Apple's Swift reference (Swift 2.2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID544): "For each entry in the capture list, a constant is initialized to the *value* of the constant or variable that has the same name in the surrounding scope [...]"

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks! –  I just wonder  why the documentation states *"... a constant is initialised ..."*. In this case of a weakly captured reference, `a` is a *variable* in the closure.

Comment: Hi @MartinR, why `var closure = { [weak a] in
    a?.stamina = 10
}` give me `a.stamina` // 10, because you say `a` in a closure is dependency from `a` outside the closure.

Comment: @Khuong: If you don't assign a new value to `a` in the closure then it references the same object as the outer  `a`. You have two (independent) pointers pointing to the same object. –  `a?.stamina = 10` does not change the value of `a`, but the value of the pointed-to object.