# How to count the amount of times a completition handler is called in swift?

Tags: swift, closures, completionhandler

```
var gameIDCount = 0
FirPickUpRead.getGameFrom(gameID: gameID, completion: { (game) in
    gameIDCount += 1
    if gameIDCount == gameIDs.count {
        comp(gamesOnDate)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call the function comp() when gameIDCount is equal to gameIDs.count. However gameIDcount is not being added to. In each of those completion closures it is 0 and becomes 1.

I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the completion handler being called somewhere else so it's taking the value of the variable when it's called. But I don't know how to rectify this.

Comment: See [How do closures capture values from previous calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839020/how-do-closures-capture-values-from-previous-calls)

Comment: You should consider using a dispatch group if you just want to schedule a given completion closure to be called after all `getGameFrom` requests have finished.

Comment: ah cheers, i'll look again but i stuggled to relate that answer to mine honey. And hamish thanks, I don't really know anything about gcd, how could I be using a dispatch group?